# How to change date format and have concatenated string matches in mongodb query filter?

Tags: python, algorithm, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm matching two collections residing in 2 different databases over a criteria and creates a new collection for records that matches this criterion.

Below is working with simple criteria, but I need a different criterion.

#### Definitions

```
function insertBatch(collection, documents) {
  var bulkInsert = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  var insertedIds = [];
  var id;
  documents.forEach(function(doc) {
    id = doc._id;
    // Insert without raising an error for duplicates
    bulkInsert.find({_id: id}).upsert().replaceOne(doc);
    insertedIds.push(id);
  });
  bulkInsert.execute();
  return insertedIds;
}

function moveDocuments(sourceCollection, targetCollection, filter, batchSize) {
 print("Moving " + sourceCollection.find(filter).count() + " documents from " + sourceCollection + " to " + targetCollection);
  var count;
  while ((count = sourceCollection.find(filter).count()) > 0) {
    print(count + " documents remaining");
    sourceDocs = sourceCollection.find(filter).limit(batchSize);
    idsOfCopiedDocs = insertBatch(targetCollection, sourceDocs);

    targetDocs = targetCollection.find({_id: {$in: idsOfCopiedDocs}});
  }
  print("Done!")
}
```

#### Call

```
var db2 = new Mongo("<URI_1>").getDB("analy")
var db = new Mongo("<URI_2>").getDB("clone")
var readDocs= db2.coll1
var writeDocs= db.temp_coll
var Urls = new Mongo("<URI_2>").getDB("clone").myCollection.distinct("Url" ,{})
var filter= {"Url": {$in: Urls }}
moveDocuments(readDocs, writeDocs, filter, 10932)
```

In a nutshell, my criterion is distinct `"Url"` string. Instead, I want `Url + Date` string to be my criterion. There are 2 problems:

1. In one collection, the date is in format `ISODate("2016-03-14T13:42:00.000+0000")` and in other collection the date format is `"2018-10-22T14:34:40Z"`. So, How to make them uniform so that they match each other?
2. Assuming, we get a solution to `1.`, and we create a new array having concatenated strings `UrlsAndDate` instead of `Urls`. How would we create a similar concatenated field on the fly and match it in the other collection?

For example: (non-functional code!)

```
var UrlsAndDate = new Mongo("<URI_2>").getDB("clone").myCollection.distinct("Url"+"formated_Date" ,{})
var filter= {"Url"+"formated_Date": {$in: Urls }}
readDocs.find(filter)
...and do the same stuff as above!
```

Any suggestions?

#### Got a brute force solution, but isn't feasible!

Problem:
I want to merge 2 collections `mycoll` & `coll1`. Both have a field name `Url` and Date. `mycoll` has `35000` docs and `coll1` has 4.7M docs(16+gb)-can't load into m/m.

Algo, written using pymongo client :

1. iterate over `mycoll`

   - create a `src` string "url+common_date_format"
   - Try to find a match in `coll1`, since, `coll1` is big I can't load it in m/m and treat as dictionary!. So, I'm iterating over each doc in this collection again and again.

     2. iterate over `coll1`

        - create a destination string "url+common_date_format"
          if `src_string` == `dest_string`
          insert this doc in a new collection called temp_coll
          This is a terrible algorithm since O(35000*4.7M), would take ages to complete!. If I could load 4.7M in m/m then the run time will reduce to O(35000), that's doable!

Any suggestions for another algorithm!

Comment: Can there be more than one doc with same {url, date} in collection which has 4.7M records?

Comment: nope, There might be >1 url that matches, that's why I decided to pair with the date so that I can get the unique match!.

Comment: So you are saying combination of url and date will be unique?

Comment: yes!, do you have a better algo for it? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is create compound index with `{url: 1, date: 1}` on collections if they don't already exist. Say collection `A` has 35k docs and collection `B` has 4.7M docs. We can't load whole 4.7M docs data in-memory. You are iterating over cursor object of `B` in inner loop. I assume once that cursor object is exhausted you are querying the collection again.

Some observations to make here why are we iterating over 4.7M docs each time. Instead of fetching all 4.7M docs and then matching, we could just fetch docs that match url and date for each doc in `A`. Converting `a_doc` date to `b_doc` format and then querying would be better than making both to common format which forces us to do 4.7M docs iteration. Read the below pseudo code.

```py
a_docs = a_collection.find()
c_docs = []
for doc in a_docs:
    url = doc.url
    date = doc.date
    date = convert_to_b_collection_date_format(date)
    query = {'url': url, 'date': date}
    b_doc = b_collection.find(query)
    c_docs.append(b_doc)
c_docs = covert_c_docs_to_required_format(c_docs)
c_collection.insert_many(c_docs)
```

Above we are looping over 35k docs and filter for each doc. Given that we have indexes created already lookup takes logarithmic time, which seems reasonable.